# Qgis network analysis why find vertex return always -1

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I'm trying to compute the shortest path between points using the QGIS networkanalysis library. But the graph.findVertex always return -1.

Basically what I'm trying to do is :
1/ Given a set of points, create a grid. The size of the grid is define by the poins bounding box
2/ transform all the cells' grid to point (centroid)
3/ For each cell's centroid compute the shortest path with the set of points

My script works fine with no error, but the graph.findVertex() function always return -1. It's like my points are not tied to the graph...

My code is available on pastebin :
http://pastebin.com/u6n4tSkz

Do you know what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you confirm that graph and grid are in the same CRS?

Comment: Hi @underdark, thanks for your help. The CRS iis the same for both layers (EPSG:32740). This is one of the first I've checked, but unfortunately it was not that simple :(

Answer (score 1):

Check if your graph contains the points you later want to find using findVertex. According to http://qgis.org/api/qgsgraph_8cpp_source.html, the routing graph has to contain the exact point:

```
72 int QgsGraph::findVertex( const QgsPoint& pt ) const
73 {
74   int i = 0;
75   for ( i = 0; i < mGraphVertexes.size(); ++i )
76   {
77     if ( mGraphVertexes[ i ].point() == pt )
78     {
79       return i;
80     }
81   }
82   return -1;
83 }
```

Try and check if the tying in [makeGraph](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsGraphDirector.html#a8dbb8542a9e1ee222b9b9ba4da28ba81) failed:

> Note
>   if tiedPoints[i]==QgsPoint(0.0,0.0) then tied failed.

Comment: Hi undertak, the number of points seems to be good. If I do  print len(gridCentroidFeats) & print len(processing.features(self.pointLayer)) the total number is 770 + 12. And if I do a  print len(tiedPoints) the result is 782. So all the points seem to be here.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion I've tried to loop on the tiedPoints to check the geometry. So if I do a  "for tiedPoint in tiedPoints: print tiedPoint.wellKnownText()" the result is POINT(0 -0), POINT(0 -0), POINT(0 -0)...

Comment: Hi underdark, do you have any idea why the makeGraph function has failed ? I've got no errors and the code seems to be fine...  Thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe the distances are too big. Can you share test data?

Comment: Hi Underdark. Here you will find the data, a qgis project and the python code : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96280295/shared_data.zip Thanks :)

Comment: Hi underdark, by chance have you been able to find what is wrong with my data or the script ? Thanks

Comment: I tried your data with a basic script but no luck. One theory was that issues might be due to different parts of the network being unconnected. Not sure yet where the issue is, sorry. Might be easier to create your own graph object, like I did in https://github.com/anitagraser/QGIS-resources/blob/master/qgis2/scripts/ogd/idf_router.py

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help. You saved me a lot of time by confirm me that it doesn't work for you as well. I will try your solution and create my own graph object. Thanks again.